# Launch text editor from Fastlane?

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm trying to launch a text editor from within a Fastlane action using `sh`:

```
  private_lane :edit_file do |options|
    sh "nano #{options[:file]}"
  end
```

This doesn't work-- the action just hangs when executing `sh` without displaying the editor UI.

So, what's the proper way to launch a CLI editor from within an action?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can run interactive tools like `nano` using Fastlane?

Answer (score 2):

For now you can use...

```
private_lane :edit_file do |options|
    system('vim', options[:file])
end
```

---

There isn't a built in way to do this right now but I've actually been thinking about adding this. I added an issue for this for me to work on - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15939

I might be able to get to it this week

Comment: Thanks, Josh!  This is great. And a built-in solution would be awesome!